# ZF2- File upload with Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have got **2 Entities** *(News & Images)* with **Fieldset** and **Form**.

And I want to upload the data (filename's image) to my tables and save the file in some folder
Tables: *IMAGES[id,filename, image_text, news_id], NEWS[id,title, sec(tion)_id, images_id]*.

**Entity\News**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="news")
*/
class News
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=48) */
    protected $titulo;

    /**
    * @var \Admin\Entity\Sections
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Sections")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sec_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $section;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="images_id")
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Images", mappedBy="news_id", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    protected $images;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /*************
    **  SETTERS **
    *************/

    /**
    * @param integer $id
    * @return Noticias
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $title
    * @return Noticias
    */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param integer $section
    * @return Noticias
    */
    public function setSection($section)
    {
        $this->section = $section;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $images
    * @return Noticias
    */
    public function setImages($images)
    {
        $this->images = $images;
        return $this;
    }


    /*************
    **  GETTERS **
    *************/

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
    * Get Seccion
    * @return \Admin\Entity\Sections
    */
    public function getSection()
    {
        return $this->section;
    }

    /**
     * Get images
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the object to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArrayCopy() 
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    /**
     * Populate from an array.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function exchangeArray ($data = array()) 
    {
        $this->id = $data['id'];
        $this->title = $data['title'];
        $this->section = $data['sec_id'];
        $this->images_id = $data['images_id'];
    }
}
```

**Entity\Images**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="images")
*/
class Images
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="images", type="string", length=255)
    */
    protected $images;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $image_text;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\News", inversedBy="images")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $news_id;

    /**
    * @param integer $id
    * @return Images
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $images
    * @return Images
    */
    public function setNombre($images)
    {
        $this->images = $images;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $image_text
    * @return Images
    */
    public function setImage_text($image_text)
    {
        $this->image_text = $image_text;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get images
    * @return string
    */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
    * Get FileName
    * @return string
    */
    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $news_id
     * @return Images
     */
    public function setNews_id($news_id)
    {
        $this->news_id = $news_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get not_id
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNews_id()
    {
        return $this->news_id;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the object to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArrayCopy() 
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    /**
     * Populate from an array.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function exchangeArray ($data = array()) 
    {
        $this->filename = $data['filename'];
        $this->image_text = $data['image_text'];
        $this->news_id = $data['news_id'];
    }
}
```

**Form\NewsFieldset**

```
    <?php
    namespace Admin\Form;

    use Admin\Entity\News;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
    use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
    use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

    class NewsFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
    {
        public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
        {
            parent::__construct('news');

            $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Admin\Entity\News'))->setObject(new News());

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'required'  => 'required',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Título',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'maxlength' => '100',
                ),
            ));

            $imagesFieldset = new \Admin\Form\ImagesFieldset($objectManager);
            $this->add(array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                'name'    => 'images',
                'options' => array(
                    'count' => 1,
                    'target_element' => $imagesFieldset
                )
            ));

        }
        public function getInputFilterSpecification()
        {
            return array(
                'title' => array(
                    'required' => true
                ),
            );
        }
    }

Form\ImagesFieldset

<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\Images;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class ImagenesFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('images');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Admin\Entity\Images'))->setObject(new Images());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'filename',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'image_text',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'news_id',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            /*'imagen' => array(
                'required' => true
            ),*/
        );
    }
}
```

**Form\NewsForm**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\News;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class NewsForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('new_news');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, '\Admin\Entity\News'));

        $newsFieldset = new \Admin\Form\NewsFieldset($objectManager);
        $newsFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($newsFieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                'id' => 'enviar',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

**Create action**

```
   public function createAction()
    {
        $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        $form = new \Admin\Form\NewsForm($objectManager);
        $noticia = new \Admin\Entity\News();

        $imagenes = new \Admin\Entity\Images();

        $form->bind($noticia);

        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $data = array_merge_recursive(
                $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
                $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
            );
            $form->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                print_r($form->getData());
            }
        }
        return new ViewModel([
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

**View**

```
<table>
<td><?php echo $this->formRow($noticia->get('title')); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->formRow($noticia->get('images')); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->formRow($noticia->get('image_text')); ?></td>
</table>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It isn't return an array from images input-file.

Comment: Admin\Entity\News Object ( [id:protected] => [tile:protected] => Title [imagenes:protected] => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object ( [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: Try adding the [`File\RenameUpload`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.filter.file.rename-upload.html#zend-filter-file-rename-upload) filter to the Input on the form's InputFilter that corresponds to the file field.

Comment: @AdamLundrigan thank you, how can I add File\RenameUpload to my Form? I use it in my action, but I need to upload my image in ajax

Comment: You could either build an entire InputFilter tree which matches the structure of your form ([see docs here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html)) then attach the InputFilter to your Form object.  Alternatively you could hint the InputFilter specification on your fieldset [like the docs show here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#hinting-to-the-input-filter)